# Swift iOS -In ViewWIllAppear How to Check If ImagePicker is Being Presented or Dismissed While Switching Tabs or The View Is Being Pushed On/Off?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, dismiss, viewwillappear

I have a tabBarController and in one of the tabs is a view named view2. In view2 have some code that runs in viewWillAppear. I also have an UIImagePickerController in view2.

```
fileprivate var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        runSomeCode()
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
           imageView.image = image
           imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I realize that every time the imagePicker is presented then dismissed then inside viewWillAppear runSomeCode() runs. I don't want it to keep getting called.

I initially was using this code below but I realized that the code in viewWillAppear only runs if the view2 is being pushed on. If I switch tabs and come back it won't run.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       if (isMovingToParentViewController) || (isBeingPresented){

           runSomeCode()
       }else{
           //runs when switching tabs but also runs after the imagePicker is dismissed
       }
}
```

How can I check if the imagePicker is being presented or dismissed so that my code in viewWillAppear won't run?

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31686885/50255

Comment: @ChrisAllwein Thanks :) Why don't you refer to that link as the accepted answer so i can update you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Even though the accepted answer with the so link works I found something easier. With the accepted answer you have to check wether the view is being pushed on AND wether it's being shown by a tab switch using a bool value and the TabBarDelegates. It works but it's a lot of work. My main concern was the code not running while the imagePicker was being presented or dismissed.

With this imagePicker test in viewWillAppear `runSomeCode()` only runs if the view is being pushed on and if there is a tab switch back to this view from another tab but it won't run if the imagePicker is being presented or dismissed:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       if imagePicker.isBeingDismissed == false{

           runSomeCode()
       }
}
```

And here is how you would get the same effect in viewWillDisappear. `runSomeCode()` only runs if the view is being popped off and if there is a tab switch from this view to another tab but it won't run if the imagePicker is being presented or dismissed::

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

       if imagePicker.isBeingPresented == false{

           runSomeCode()
       }
}
```